# What is the difference between Mathnet.Numerics and Mathnet.Numerics.Signed?

Tags: c#, mathnet-numerics, math.net

There are two different nuget packages, `MathNet.Numerics` and `MathNet.Numerics.Signed`. How are they different? And does signed package include all features from `MathNet.Numerics`?

Comment: Docs for Signed state "This package contains strong-named assemblies for legacy use cases (not recommended).". 450 people downloaded MathNet.Numerics.Signed 4.70 compared to 15,000 people using the non-strong-name version. Read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/strong-named-assemblies and then (probably) use the normal version